# Azure SQL Reporting to VM

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-reporting

Now, SQL Azure Reporting Service deprecated.
I have 5GB database.
It is possible to deploy VM with express edition SQL and work with reports on it, still use old SQL Azure database in production ?
It need replication ? or Reporting Services may be run at another server ?
Thank you!

Comment: express edition's reporting service won't be able to connect to a sql azure database, neither the web edition.  At least the standard edition is required, which is, kind of, pricey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install standard SQL Server Reporting Services on the VM (or better, a Cloud Service), and connect to your actual 5GB SQL database via a standard Connection String. I would not go down the path of replicating data unless you are looking to create a data warehouse for performance.

Here is a great article that may help get you started:

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1950/how-to-connect-to-sql-azure-using-sql-server-reporting-services-2008-r2/

Comment: Out clients use SQL Repoting on SQL Azure instance with Web UI. It is possible to use VM SQL server reporting throung Web interface ?

Comment: Absolutely. The VM is completely "your" machine. So all you'll need to do is install SSRS on the VM, and the web interface can be put on the public internet by configuring IIS accordingly (port, firewall, etc.)